# PostgreSQL service plus QGIS authentication combination

Tags: qgis, authentication

I have a PostgreSQL service "my_service" configured with a host and port.
I have a QGIS Basic Authentication authentication configuration "configa" configured with a username and password.

Can I make QGIS automatically use the authentication configuration "configa" whenever the service "my_service" is used, for layers or in the browser?

Both a GUI or a PyQGIS API code answer would be satisfactory.

Comment: I guess you have to add the configuration to authdb with python API like said in the pycookbook , then set the datasource path according as the layer would need to connect. this section : 13.3.2 Populate authdb with a new Authentication Configuration entry, show some exemple.